# NightmareJS not able to evaluate using vo

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, electron, nightmare

I am attempting to using NightmareJS v2 and Vo with Node.JS to look through a few search terms and gather data from them. My code can be seen below:

```
const nightmare = require('nightmare'),
  vo = require('vo'),
  nbot = nightmare({ title: 'Bot',
                        show: true });

const searchTerms = ['spacex', 'tesla', 'elon musk', 'hyperloop']; // EXAMPLE SEARCH TERMS

vo(run)(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
});

function * run() {
  yield nbot.goto('http://google.com');

  yield * forEach(searchTerms, gen);

  yield nbot.end()
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result) // STUFF SHOULD BE LOGGED HERE
  });
}

function * gen(item) {
  yield nbot.wait('input[title="Search"]')
            .click('input[title="Search"]')
            .type('input[title="Search"]', item)
            .click('input[name="btnK"]')
            .wait(100)
            .screenshot(item + '.png')
            .insert('input[title="Search"]', '')
            .evaluate(function() {
              return 'foobar' // STUFF RETURNED HERE
            })
}

function * forEach (arr, fn) { // NEEDED BECAUSE FOREACH DOESN'T WORK IN GENERATORS
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    yield * fn(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

According to NightmareJS's docs, if you return something inside of `evaluate` then it is spit out when you use `then`. When I try this I get undefined. I assume it is something with the generators but I am new to them so I can't tell. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example is *close*, but it looks like you're mixing and matching generator with Promise syntax.  The `.evaluate()` method does behave as you describe, but when you're using `vo` (or `co`), `.then()` will be taken care of and managed for you, returning what would be the value of `.then()` back to the left-hand side of the `yield` expression if one is defined.  Also, for what it's worth, your generators do not return values, and as such you will (correctly) get `undefined`.

[This](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/537#issuecomment-197603932) goes into a bit more depth on iterators, generators, promises, and `vo`/`co`.  You might also want to have a look at [`nightmare-examples`](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/) document on [`vo`](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/beginner/vo.md).

Finally, your example, modified to return results from `gen`, through `forEach` up to `run`:

```
const nightmare = require('nightmare'),
  vo = require('vo'),
  nbot = nightmare({
    title: 'Bot',
    show: true
  });

const searchTerms = ['spacex', 'tesla', 'elon musk', 'hyperloop']; // EXAMPLE SEARCH TERMS

vo(run)(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
});

function* run() {
  yield nbot.goto('http://google.com');

  var results = yield * forEach(searchTerms, gen);
  console.log(results);
  yield nbot.end();
}

function* gen(item) {
  var value = yield nbot.wait('input[title="Search"]')
    .click('input[title="Search"]')
    .type('input[title="Search"]', item)
    .click('input[name="btnK"]')
    .wait(100)
    .screenshot(item + '.png')
    .insert('input[title="Search"]', '')
    .evaluate(function() {
      return 'foobar' // STUFF RETURNED HERE
    });

  return value;
}

function* forEach(arr, fn) { // NEEDED BECAUSE FOREACH DOESN'T WORK IN GENERATORS
  let i;
  var results = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    results.push(yield * fn(arr[i]));
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But, I actually solved the problem yesterday after messing with it for an hour or so. I'll mark your answer as the accepted one to assist others with a problem like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Great example! The provided example didn't work in my case by default (IP from Germany).

Here a little fix for a general search:

```
const nightmare = require('nightmare'),
  vo = require('vo'),
  nbot = nightmare({
    title: 'Bot',
    show: true
  });

const searchTerms = ['spacex', 'tesla', 'elon musk', 'hyperloop']; // EXAMPLE SEARCH TERMS

vo(run)(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
});

function* run() {
  yield nbot.goto('http://google.com');

  var results = yield * forEach(searchTerms, gen);
  console.log(results);
  yield nbot.end();
}

function* gen(item) {
  var inputTitle
  var value = yield nbot
    .evaluate(() => {
      return document.getElementById("lst-ib").title
    })
    .then((lang) => {
      inputTitle = 'input[title="' + lang + '"]'
      return true
    });
  yield nbot
    .wait(inputTitle)
    .click(inputTitle)
    .type(inputTitle, item)
    .click('input[name="btnK"]')
    .wait(100)
    .screenshot(item + '.png')
    .insert(inputTitle, '')
    .evaluate(function() {
      return 'foobar' // STUFF RETURNED HERE
    });

  return value;
}

function* forEach(arr, fn) { // NEEDED BECAUSE FOREACH DOESN'T WORK IN GENERATORS
  let i;
  var results = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    results.push(yield * fn(arr[i]));
  }
  return results;
}
```